# Role based User profile template

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to have a different user template for each role, but I can't figure it out how do do it.

I've added a preprocess function in my themename.theme like this:

```
function ras_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

    $variables['role'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
}
```

and then used role in my user.html.twig like this:

```
{% if role == 'administrator' %}
   <p>Hello, admin</p>
{% elseif role == 'anonymous' %}
   <p>Hi, stranger</p>
{% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work as I would expect.

Comment: I think getRoles() is returning array, that's why it's not working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Can you please give me a hint on how I can check against and array?

Comment: {% if myVar in myArray %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) like below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_user_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  if (in_array('YOUR ROLE',$roles)) {
    $suggestions[] = 'user__'.ROLENAME;
  }
}
```

and you have to create

> user--YOURROLE.html.twig

in order to get a specific template for the user based on their role.